# Synchronize Trello accounts with Active Directory or LDAP

Tags: trello

Is there any way to synchronize Trello accounts with Active Directory?

This would not just be a one-time import. I would like passwords to synchronize so that users have single-sign-on. (If users have to remember yet another password, I'm not confident that they will adopt Trello.) I am willing to pay for a plugin or service that does this.

My 35-person company is using [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/intl/en/enterprise/apps/business/), and we are heavy users of [Trello](https://trello.com/). Trello can use Google Apps authentication so my coworkers have single sign on to their Trello boards.

Now I would like to roll out Trello to our 1000+-person parent company. However, the parent company does not use Google Apps. They use Microsoft Windows / Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't currently exist in Trello.

Answer (score 1):

You can track their upcoming features here - however at this time nothing currently is listed.

https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c